# How to change a chart Title automatically according to the data

Tags: python, regression, seaborn

I have code that creates seaborn regplots.
My goal is to run this code every time for a specific date and hour on that date.
The problem is that I need to change the date and the hour in the title every time I run this plots. I want to do this automatically, I thought to use format but confused how to do it inside a string.

This is the way I create the chart:

```
#Filter/Create the database based on the dat and the hour
# the date and hour for the title should come from here

byDH=df_NDVIall[(df_NDVIall.index.get_level_values('date')=='6/23/2019')&(df_NDVIall.index.get_level_values('hour') == '12:00')]['NDVI']
NITbyDH=df_Nit[['plant','nitrogen']]


merged_data=pd.merge(byDH.to_frame(),NITbyDH,how='inner',on='plant')
merged_data.head(18)

import seaborn as sns

#Define X and Y
x = merged_data['NDVI']
y = merged_data['nitrogen']

#The function
def give_me_scatter(x, y, title, xlabel, ylabel):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    #print('slope:',slope)
    #print('intercept:',intercept)
    #print('R:',r_value)
    #print('R^2:',(r_value**2))  

    # use line_kws to set line label for legend
    plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,6.5))
    ax = sns.regplot(x='NDVI', y='nitrogen', data=merged_data, color='b', line_kws={'label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope,intercept)})
    ax = sns.regplot(x='NDVI', y='nitrogen', data=merged_data, color='b', line_kws={'label':"R^2={0:.3}".format(r_value**2)})
    ax.set_title('NDVI vs Nitrogen% ')

    # plot legend
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

    # plot legend

    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

#get scatter plot

give_me_scatter(x, y, 'NDVI vs Nitrogen ', 'NDVI', 'Nitrogen %')
```

*I can't share my database

*My end goal is to add the date and the hour to the title automatically without changing the title manualy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the date and time in variables, then you can use those to write in a string to use as a title (which you were not using in your function initially)

```
date_to_plot = '6/23/2019'
time_to_plot = '12:00'

byDH=df_NDVIall[(df_NDVIall.index.get_level_values('date')==date_to_plot)&(df_NDVIall.index.get_level_values('hour') == time_to_plot)]['NDVI']
(...)

def give_me_scatter(x, y, title, xlabel, ylabel):
    (...)
    ax.set_title(title)
    (...)

#get scatter plot
give_me_scatter(x, y, 'NDVI vs Nitrogen on {} {}'.format(date_to_plot, time_to_plot), 'NDVI', 'Nitrogen %')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package called datetime. Then you can do the following to get the current date:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
```

Of course, you can then format this in a way you want.
HEre is a bit more infformation with examples: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-datetime

So you only need to create a variable and assign to it the formatted date/time.